# Is there a way to have password-less SQL server login for another user without kerberos enabled?

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, ntlm

I am connecting to SQL server with JDBC.

I am able to use Integrated authentication with JDBC to connect to a SQL Server 2016 instance as the current logged in user, and I did not have to supply a password. The only auth scheme enabled in my sql server is NTLM.

I want to do this same thing for another user without having to have access to this user's password.

Can I create a keytab for a user and use integrated authentication **without** enabling kerberos on the SQL server instance?

Or is there some other way to "save" the credentials of a user and use them to log into SQL server without enabling kerberos on sql server?

Thanks.